# core was generated by springloaded.jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-loaded

I use springloaded-1.2.3.jar to implement hot deploy in my project .And my project run with springboot in Linux. i run the main class with -javaagent springloaded.jar -noverify. it works to hot deploy, but problem is Everytime I run the project for about 1 days, the project will be down ,and generate corefiles and hs_err_pid logs.
Does anyone meet this problem?

the part of the content of the hs_err_pid.log as follow:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8175626f4b, pid=13320, tid=140193591465728
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b26) (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x367f4b]  GraphBuilder::try_inline_full(ciMethod*, bool, Bytecodes::Code, Instruction*)+0x2fb
#
```